# Set dependency for package from EPEL in spec file

Tags: dependencies, rpm, epel

I'm writing a spec file for software that depends on `php-mcrypt`.  My target OS is `CentOS 6.5` `php-mcrypt` isn't in the `CentOS` repositories, but it is in `EPEL`.  Is there a better way to satisfy this dependency on the `Requires:` line rather than manually installing `EPEL` in `%pre`?  I really don't like the idea of forcing the install of another repo in an `RPM`, but I also don't like it when `RPM`s fail to install over a dependency that doesn't seem to exist until someone gets clever enough to start searching through various foreign repos.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: How did you "manually install EPEL in %pre"? Because afaik %pre gets only executed if there are no unresolved dependencies. So in your (and my) case, it would not execute the installation of EPEL, because it cannot find the requirements (which, in turn, require EPEL to already be installed).
I'm facing a similar problem here and if this worked, it would be great (even though it's a bit hacky).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a better way to indicate this specific detail on the `Requires` line.

The only thing you could do, other than your suggestions, would be to also depend on the `epel-release` package which would at least give them a more specific hint in the correct direction. The only problem/downside to this is that you then **depend** on their having installed that package/repo instead of just having installed the `EPEL` `php-mcrypt` package on their own/etc.